# Strange crashes during CUFFT 1-D FFT

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, cuda, fft

I have this code and it crashes every 1-2th launch.
I have tried use malloc/cudaMallocHost/cudeMalloc but it was useless. It think it happens due to manual cufftComplex initialization but prove it a can't because without data I can't get fft. Could you help me eliminate this crashes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
cufftHandle plan;
cufftComplex *data;
cufftComplex *digits;
cufftComplex *h_data;

cudaMallocHost((void**)&digits, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8);
digits[0].x = 12.5f; digits[0].y = 0.0f;
digits[1].x = 66.23f; digits[1].y = 0.0f;
digits[2].x = 35.1f; digits[2].y = 0.0f;
digits[3].x = 16.7f; digits[3].y = 0.0f;
digits[4].x = 14.83f; digits[4].y = 0.0f;
digits[5].x = 55.1f; digits[5].y = 0.0f;
digits[6].x = 11.7f; digits[6].y = 0.0f;
digits[7].x = 18.83f; digits[7].y = 0.0f;

cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8);

cudaMemcpy(data, digits, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, 8, CUFFT_C2C, 1) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cufftPlan1d CUFFT_C2C failed\n");
    return 1;
}

if (cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data, CUFFT_FORWARD) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cufftExecC2C CUFFT_FORWARD failed\n");
    return 1;
}

if (cudaMalloc((void**)&h_data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8) != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cudaMalloc((void**)&h_data failed\n");
    return 1;
}

cudaMemcpy(h_data, data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


printf("\nOriginal:\n");
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    printf("\nRe:%2.5f   Im:%2.5f", digits[i].x, digits[i].y);
} 

printf("\n\n1D-FFT:\n");
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    printf("\nRe:%2.5f   Im:%2.5f", h_data[i].x, h_data[i].y);
} 

cudaFree(digits);
cudaFree(data);
cudaFree(h_data);
cufftDestroy(plan);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basic problem is improper mixing of host and device memory pointers. You have assigned the address of a device memory allocation (using cudaMalloc) to `h_data` , but are trying to use it as a pointer to an address in host memory. That won't work and is producing the host segmentation fault you are seeing. Your example should look something like:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex *data, *digits, *h_data;

    digits = (cufftComplex *)malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex)*8);
    digits[0].x = 12.5f; digits[0].y = 0.0f;
    digits[1].x = 66.23f; digits[1].y = 0.0f;
    digits[2].x = 35.1f; digits[2].y = 0.0f;
    digits[3].x = 16.7f; digits[3].y = 0.0f;
    digits[4].x = 14.83f; digits[4].y = 0.0f;
    digits[5].x = 55.1f; digits[5].y = 0.0f;
    digits[6].x = 11.7f; digits[6].y = 0.0f;
    digits[7].x = 18.83f; digits[7].y = 0.0f;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8);
    cudaMemcpy(data, digits, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, 8, CUFFT_C2C, 1) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cufftPlan1d CUFFT_C2C failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data, CUFFT_FORWARD) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cufftExecC2C CUFFT_FORWARD failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    h_data = (cufftComplex *)malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex)*8);
    cudaMemcpy(h_data, data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\nOriginal:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        printf("\nRe:%2.5f   Im:%2.5f", digits[i].x, digits[i].y);
    } 

    printf("\n\n1D-FFT:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        printf("\nRe:%2.5f   Im:%2.5f", h_data[i].x, h_data[i].y);
    } 

    free(digits);
    free(h_data);
    cudaFree(data);
    cufftDestroy(plan);
}
```

Note that you should use plain `malloc` or the C++ `new` operator to allocate host side memory rather than `cudaMallocHost`, unless you understand very well what the latter API does and why you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
if (cudaMalloc((void**)&h_data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8) != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cudaMalloc((void**)&h_data failed\n");
    return 1;
}
```

try:

```
if (cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*8) != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda: cudaMalloc((void**)&h_data failed\n");
    return 1;
}
```

since you're copying bytes back to the cpu.

The documentation provides hints on `cudaMallocHost` vs `malloc` usage:

> **cudaError_t cudaMallocHost     (   void **     ptr,        size_t      size        )**
>
> *Allocates size bytes of host memory that is page-locked and accessible
>   to the device. The driver tracks the virtual memory ranges allocated
>   with this function and automatically accelerates calls to functions
>   such as cudaMemcpy*(). Since the memory can be accessed directly by
>   the device, it can be read or written with much higher bandwidth than
>   pageable memory obtained with functions such as malloc(). Allocating
>   excessive amounts of memory with cudaMallocHost() may degrade system
>   performance, since it reduces the amount of memory available to the
>   system for paging. As a result, this function is best used sparingly
>   to allocate staging areas for data exchange between host and device.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, try running running your app under the CUDA debugger, with memory checking turned on:

```
nvcc –g –G myapp.cu –o myapp
cuda-gdb myapp
(cuda-gdb) set cuda memcheck on 
(cuda-gdb) run
```

If you are on Windows, select `Nsight | Enable CUDA Memory Checker` and run your code from the built-in CUDA debugger. `Nsight | Start CUDA Debugging`.

Also, add code to your app to check the return values from each of the CUDA calls.

See for more information about the CUDA Memchecker:

http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation#CUDA-MemcheckUserManual

Comment: He is getting a host side segmentation fault error, cuda-gdb is total overkill for this.

Comment: @talonmies: The bug you found would have caused the program to crash every time, not every "1-2th launch" as stated in the question. Also, the type of error was not included in the question. I don't think it's overkill to advice CUDA beginners to try running their program in the debugger as the very first step when troubleshooting. There is a tremendous information there that is available "for free" and beginners don't, in general, tap into it. Because of that, I decided to add a reply showing him how to fish, instead of giving him the fish.